# Check Varchar Value is Numeric without overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with `PostalCode` Column that type's is `Char(10)`, I use the following Select query:

```
SELECT [Fm].[Id], [Sdp].[FirstName], [Sdp].[LastName], [Sdp].[SSN],
[Sdp].[StoreName],
case when isnumeric([Sdp].[PostalCode]) = 1 then CONVERT(CHAR(10),[Sdp].[PostalCode]) 
else '0' end,  [Fc].[Id], [Sdp].[Address]

FROM [SRM].[SiteMembers].[DProfile] AS [Sdp]
INNER JOIN [SRM].[SiteMembers].[Member] AS [Sm]
ON [Sdp].[Member_Id] = [Sm].[Id]
INNER JOIN [FRM].[Members].[Member] AS [Fm]
ON [Sm].[UserId] = [Fm].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [SRM].[General].[City] AS [Sc]
ON [Sdp].[City_Id]=[Sc].[Id]
INNER JOIN [FRM].[General].[City] AS [Fc]
ON [Fc].[Title]=[Sc].[Title] 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Whit this script the Over flow error raised like this:

```
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The conversion of the varchar value '4153675759' overflowed an int column.
```

I ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373964/merge-two-sql-script-use-if-condition-in-select-query/9374130#9374130) and I don't want back to past with 2 scripts, So is there any way to check the PostalCode is numeric (and I mean numeric not int) without any error?

Comment: That `CASE...` seems malformed - you normally have to compare the result of `ISNUMERIC` to `1` or `0`. And as I said on your other question, `ISNUMERIC` is rarely the right function to use. Finally, there's no conversion to `int` in the above query, so I really suspect it isn't your actual query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check that a `(n)(var)char` value consists of digits and only digits, then a simply double negative `LIKE` will work:

```
PostalCode not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

which will only be true if there are no non-digits within the string.

Comment: Thank you for answer And I actually find the following worked correctly: `CASE WHEN RTRIM([Sdp].[PostalCode])='' THEN '0' ELSE CASE WHEN RTRIM([Sdp].[PostalCode]) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN RTRIM([Sdp].[PostalCode]) ELSE '0' END END` Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
case 
    when [Sdp].[PostalCode] like '%[^0-9]%' 
        then 0 else CONVERT(CHAR(10),[Sdp].[PostalCode]) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try BIGINT. Each of the numeric datatypes have a range. For example SMAIINT ranges from +32767 till -32768. TINYINT ranges from 0 to 255